# django.db.migrations.exceptions.MigrationSchemaMissing: Unable to create the django_migrations table

Tags: django, postgresql

When I use the GaussDB database, I use the Django framework, and then fill in the public network ip, port, user name, password, database name and other instances in the settings configuration item.
But when importing the table, Django reported an error:

> django.db.migrations.exceptions.MigrationSchemaMissing: Unable to
> create the   django_migrations table (dn_6001_6002_6003: permission
> denied for schema public),

Which means that the table cannot be created in the public schema.
I originally wanted to create it under root, but the search_path under root doesn't seem to have any effect, I also set the scan path, but all scanned schemas are said to be under the public path.
What should I do now?

Comment: GaussDB is based on pgsql, so maybe you should run migration with user postgres